# How would I initialize an array of Maps in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, hashmap, priority-queue, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to initialize an array of Maps in C++, and am having trouble.

I'd like each element of the array to contain an integer (key), and string (value), pair, so I figured that an array of Maps would be a good idea, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to initialize.

```
map <int, string> * myArray;
```

works, but the following does not work:

```
myArray = new map <int, string> [10];
```

and I'm not sure why.

I haven't been able to find references on this, since I'm keen on using an array in my code, not a Vector, which is far more well-documented. Would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: `std::map<int,double>* maps = new std::map<int,double>[10];` should compile. Please post the exact code you are using and the error it gives you. "Doesn't work" is useless.

Comment: If each element of your array is only supposed to be a key-value pair, where does the map come from? According to your second sentence, you want a `std::pair<int, std::string>[N]`. Also, there are not many reasons to prefer arrays over vectors; what's yours?

Comment: Your code compile, why are you saying it does not ? Note however a map is not just a pair. Do you need a single map, an array of map or an array of pair ? What is the goal (without speaking about the solution) ?

Comment: *I'm keen on using an array in my code* -- No need to use dumb arrays or pointers.  `std::array<std::map<int, std::string>, 10> myArray;`

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is fine and should compile.

```
map <int, string> * myArray = new map<int, string>[10];
```

This default constructs 10 maps on the heap, but you said in the question that you want each element of your ARRAY to hold a key and a value. Please note, maps are not arrays and their implementation and usage is very different.

I think something that you might be looking for is

```
pair<int, string>* myArray = new pair<int, string>[10];
// or alternatively
vector<pair<int, string>> myArray(10);
```